# Making object move to a touch position - Corona SDK

Tags: physics, game-physics, coronasdk

I'm trying to get a game object to move to a touch location. I've tried numerous different ways of doing it, but all to no avail. I'm updating the objects y position every frame to keep it moving constantly forward, and I'm not sure if this is affecting adding a force or not.

Here is where I move the crow (inside an update function):

```
crow:translate((platformSpeed),0)
```

And here is where I'm trying to get the crow to move to the touch position:

```
        local function attack(xPos,yPos)

            --get magnitude of touch vector
            local magnitude = math.sqrt(xPos*2 + yPos*2)

            --normalize vector
            xPos = xPos / magnitude
            yPos = yPos / magnitude

            print(xPos..yPos)

            local forceMag = 0.1 -- change this value to apply more or less force
            --now apply the force
            crow:setLinearVelocity(xPos*forceMag, yPos*forceMag)
            --crow:applyLinearImpulse(xPos*forceMag, yPos*forceMag, crow.x, crow.y)
        end

        local function touchHandler(event)

            if (event.phase == "began") then
            end

            if (event.phase == "ended") then
                if (event.yStart>event.y+10) then
                    jump()
                else attack(event.x,event.y) end
            end

        end
```

As you can see, I've been trying linear velocity and linear impulse, but the direction is always wrong!

Any help would be great, Thanks!
Alan.

Comment: I found this which helps me a little: [Working Out An Angle To Shoot Relevant To Click Not Player](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/33806-working-out-an-angle-to-shoot-relevant-to-click-not-player/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local cow = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)  -- create your object

local trans
local function moveObject(e)
    if(trans)then
      transition.cancel(trans)
    end
    trans = transition.to(cow,{time=200,x=e.x,y=e.y})  -- move to touch position
end
Runtime:addEventListener("tap",moveObject)
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the recent question.

I have an answer to the recent question, you can check and run my sample code on a blank project to see how it works.

My code uses physics and linear velocity.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17847475/1605727